# How to generally describe all possible quasi-crystal structures in $\mathbb{R}^3$?

Tags: integer-lattices, tiling

According to what I found on Wikipedia[[1](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quasicrystal),[2](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Aperiodic_tiling#Cut-and-project_method)], you can represent any quasi-crystal structure in $\mathbb{R}^n$ by cutting a space $\mathbb{R}^N, N>n$ at an angle with the $\mathbb{R}^n$ space and then look at a periodic lattice in $\mathbb{R}^N$ and see where its points land in  $\mathbb{R}^n$.

It also vaguely mentions cutting through $\mathbb{R}^6$ to result in certain quasi-crystal structures in $\mathbb{R}^3$. There is also a linked paper which, sadly, is behind a paywall.

Is that the highest-dimensional space you need to get all the quasi-periodic tilings of $\mathbb{R}^3$? If not, where is this limit if there is one?

Also, does it suffice to take a simple cubical lattice (i.e. just look at all Integer vectors $\mathbf{x}=\left(x_i\right), x_i \in \mathbb{Z}$, or do I need to use more generic lattices? - My guess on that is that, eventually, a cubical lattice would suffice since cutting through it with some lowerdimensional space would result in a different lattice which you could then cut through at even lower dimensions to get general quasi-lattices.

So in short, is there a unified, finitely representable way to represent all quasi-crystal-structures for $\mathbb{R}^3$? And I suppose, if that isn't too much extra information, the generic version for $\mathbb{R}^n$ would be interesting too, though I do not need that right now if it's too complicated.

Lastly and perhaps obviously, what I do not care about are rotations or translations of the quasi-crystal-structure in $\mathbb{R}^3$. So I assume to achieve that I must not rotate my $\mathbb{R}^N$-space around any vector spanned by my $\mathbb{R}^3$ subspace. Is this indeed a necessary condition? Is it sufficient?

---

Somewhat related but different question I found:
[Projection of a lattice onto a subspace](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/14358/49989)

Comment: That's a lot of questions. We should start by you suggesting a definition for Quasi-crystal, as there is no standard definition in the literature.

Comment: @DanielRust I am looking for crystals and quasi-crystals that can actually happen in chemicals. Not sure what is the right definition for that but defining them as being uniformly dense structures where any local patch can be brought to locally coincide with any other such local patch or something seems fine. Approaching it from a material physics angle, choose what ever works. I have no idea how to make it more precise - I don't know how various definitions in the literature differ.

Comment: @DanielRust One thing to surely exclude is hyperbolic or spherical lattices. I only need euclidean ones. And as said, in case the general case is too complex, I'm majorly interested in the flat 3D-case. So if there are subtle differences between definitions as they approach $\infty$ Dimensions or something, that shouldn't matter at all.

Comment: Are you specifically only considering quasi-crystals which arise from the cut and project method, or just any Delone set with finite local complexity? The former is already a huge class of objects, but somewhat manageable. The latter is truly monstrous.

Comment: @DanielRust so what you are saying is that my first remark of being able to find "any" quasi-crystal by cutting through high-dimensional spaces at an angle isn't entirely correct? Based on what I quickly found just now on Delone set, I guess they (or, perhaps more restrictively, Meyer Sets?) are indeed also a definition of quasi crystals. So there are some of those that can't be achieved by the above procedure? I guess I'll be content with the smaller set of the cut-and-project method for now.

Comment: @DanielRust what I really want is an as general as possible without going overboard representation of (quasi-)crystal structures (in $\mathbb{R}^3$) which I can use in a genetic algorithm. I am supposed to find minimal energy configurations of soft particles using this method. I assume most such states will constitute classical non-quasi crystal structures but I want to avoid assumptions. The computer is supposed to answer that question after all. Cutting through rotated fixed-dimensional spaces can easily be represented by a bunch of angles. That's why I want to know ...

Comment: @DanielRust ... if there is a highest finite dimension to get to all valid quasi-crystal structures in 3D (at least those of the cut-and-project variety) or if I just have to arbitrarily stop at some number of dimensions. Would there still be a reasonable parametrization for the more complex case of Meyer or Delone sets?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are quasi-crystals arising from cut and project schemes from $\mathbb{R}^N$ to $\mathbb{R}^3$ for all $N>3$. All that is required to force aperiodicity is that the subspace being projected onto is spanned by 'rationally independent' basis vectors (the generic case in terms of measure). The integer $N$ determines how many 'tile types' there are (a tile type would be the shape of possible tiles appearing in the Voronoi tiling of the point set).

Essentially, in the generic case with canonical window, the number of tile types will be the number of $3$-faces on the unit $N$-cube which is given by ${{N}\choose{3}} 2^{N-3}$. Apart from the codimension ($N-3$) of the tiling , you can also change the direction of the subspace and the size and shape of the 'acceptance domain' (or 'window') these all affect the properties of the quasi-crystal that you can end up with. This can all be formalised, but I'm guessing that for the moment you only want a general idea of what kinds of forms these quasi-crystals can take. Even for this rather tame collection, the answer is essentially that there are an uncountable number of quasi-crystals, even up to rather weak notions of equivalence of crystals (say, up to dynamical equivalence or topological).

Things get almost impossibly more complicated if you decide you want to look at the much larger class of all FLC (finite local complexity) Delone sets or FLC Mayer sets.

There are various other methods of generating classes of quasi-crystals which you may be interested in, such that the self-similar quasicrystals related to the so-called "substitution tilings", of which there are many variants and generalisations. In-situ, these kinds of quasi-crystals are rather well understood, but one should again be careful to understand that they are only a small subcollection of all possible quasi-crystals.

Comment: @kram1032 thanks for the edit. That looks like it could be right.