# When does projecting a lattice onto a subspace give another lattice?

Tags: linear-algebra, geometry, number-theory, reference-request, vector-lattices

For a lattice $L$ and vector $v$ in $\mathbb{R}^n$ take
$L\backslash v := \{l-(\textstyle \frac{v^\dagger l}{\|v\|^2})v: l\in L\}.$
When is $L\backslash v$ a lattice?

Comment: There is a partial answer here: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/14358/projection-of-a-lattice-onto-a-subspace . But has this been covered before in some paper or textbook?

Comment: The title asks about "projecting a lattice", and the mathematical expression in the body  for $L\setminus v$ seems intended to fill out the details.  However the meaning of $v$ is unclear.  Is it meant to be a general (nonzero) vector in $\mathbb R^n$?

Comment: oops messed up, thanks.

Comment: Projection, as I think you intend the term, is a linear transformation.  The image of a lattice under a linear transformation is again a lattice, and the basis for the resulting lattice is a subset of the image of the basis for the original lattice (possibly some redundancies occur in the mapped basis image).

Comment: I believe there are cases where the result of the transformation is dense. Consider for example rotating $\mathbb{Z}^2$ and then projecting the result of rotation onto an axis

Comment: I agree that the resulting lattice might be a dense subset; does this have an implication for the Question you asked?  It is a one line Question, and would be easier to respond to in a useful way if you supplied more context.  The notation $L\setminus v$ is confusing because "backslash" is ordinarily used to mean set exclusion.  If you wanted to project $L$ onto the subspace orthogonal to some (nonzero) vector $v$, I would instead refer to the mapping directly $P: L \to L$ defined by $P(x) = x - \frac{v^T x}{||v||^2}v$, i.e. orthogonal projection onto the space of vectors perpendicular to $v$.

Comment: i think its clear, you understood it fine.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let $p\colon \Bbb R^n\to \Bbb R^{n-1}$ be a linear map of rank $n-1$. and $L\subset \Bbb R^n$ a lattice. We wonder when $p(L)$ is a lattice in $\Bbb R^{n-1}$.

Pick a basis $e_1,\ldots, e_n$ of  $L$. Then the $p(e_i)$ span $\Bbb R^{n-1}$, but are linearly dependent in an essentially unique way,
$$\tag1 c_1p(e_1)+\ldots +c_np(e_n)=0$$
with not all $c_i=0$.
We may assume wlog. that $c_n=1$.

If all $c_i$ are rational, say $c_i=\frac {a_i}{b_i}$ with $a_i\in\Bbb Z$, $b_i\in\Bbb N$, then $p(L)$ is contained in $L':=\frac {p(e_1)}{b_1}\Bbb Z+\ldots + \frac {p(e_{n-1})}{b_{n-1}}\Bbb Z$. As the listed vectors span $\Bbb R^{n-1}$, $L'$ is a lattice and $L$ then is a sublattice of it.

On the other hand, if $p(L)$ is a lattice than there is a linear dependence among $p(e_1),\ldots,p(e_n)$ that has only rational coefficients. By the essential uniqueness of $(1)$, it follows that the $c_i$ are rational.

We conclude that $p(L)$ is a lattice if and only if the coefficients in the produced linear dependency $(1)$ are (after normalizing) rational. 
In the setting of the OP, we find the $c_i$ by expressing the projecting vector $v$ because $v=\sum c_ie_i$ turns intor $0= \sum c_ip(e_i)$. The rationality criterion is then equivalent to the following:

> $L\setminus v =p(L)$ is a lattice if and only if $v$ is a multiple of a lattice vector.